# Passing variable to sql WHERE IN clause

Tags: php, mysql, variables, where-clause

I've viewed a few similar posts regarding this topic, but I haven't found them to work for me.

I have a list of checkboxes that store article ids as a value. This means when the user checks a checkbox, the ids are stored as a string and sent to the handler (something like this: "blah,blah,blah"). I will later delete the ids from the database.

My sql statement looks something like this:
    "delete from article where art_id in (".$_GET['art_id'].")"

Of course, this doesn't work because $_GET['art_id'] looks like "blah,blah,blah,blah" rather than " 'blah', 'blah', 'blah', 'blah' "

Some answers on the net mentioned spliting the string and using regex. I'm not sure what the best way is. If I wasn't clear on something, please ask and I'll clarify. Much thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sanitize, implode and then insert the string:

```
$ids = array();
$in = '';
if(isset($_GET['art_id']){
  foreach($_GET['art_id'] as $id){
    $ids[] = intval($id);
  }
  $in = implode(',', $ids);
}

$query = "delete from article where art_id in (".$in.")";
```

You might want to do additional checking in case where $_GET['art_id'] is empty, something like providing a default value or making the query only if you have the IDs

Comment: Thanks, Damien. I figured out the solution to this, but now I'm struggling with a similar problem but with strings. I need "blah,blah,blah" to look like "'blah','blah','blah'". In this case, it's already a string, so implode isn't necessary. And I can't insert an array in the sql statement. If you know how to figure this out, your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That's another question, anyway the principle stands similar

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `implode` function

[See here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Thanks, Manu. I made a quick edit to mention that when it gets to the handler, it's a string, so it looks like "blah,blah,blah" before inserting it into the sql statement.

Comment: if its and `id`, shouldn't it be an integer?

Comment: Yes, it's an integer, and I'm also forcing (int) before inserting it into the sql statement, but when I debug it using var_dump and then die, it shows quotes around it. I concatenated it the way I posted it above, perhaps that's the problem? Also, when I let the handler run (remove die), it only deletes one post rather than all of the ones that were checked.

Comment: if your `$_GET['art_id']` looks like "1,3,6,7" ( without qoutes ), then it should run. Try printing the value of `$_GET['art_id']` before you proceed to execute the query

Comment: I removed the typecast (int) before the variable and it worked. I didn't realize that forcing (int) returns only one number. Thanks a lot, Manu.

Comment: I guess now I have a similar problem but with strings. I will have to figure out a way to put quotes around each word. If you know of any way to solve this, please let me know.

Comment: use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to make convert the string into array. Once you get the array, run [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on each of the element of array. After doing this, add a quote to each element and use implode. PS : I don't know if this is the best solution, but this is a fairly simple solution.

Comment: Thanks, Manu, I imploded the array using implode("','",$list) and it works great!